# R Deep Learning with H2O vs neuralnet package

Tags: r, neural-networks, deep-learning

I had a fairly open ended question. I've been looking at deep learning architectures for neural networks for classification in R. A few packages came up, `neuralnet`, `H2O` and `nnet` I've worked with all of them. `nnet` provides only a single hidden layer so I find that a bit limiting as it can't do deep learning. `H2O` is built for scale with distributed memory, but I find it takes a really long time on reasonably sized data sets (say 100s of MB), but it lets me do deep learning. `neuralnet` allows multiple hidden layers. If you take out the feature to do random dropouts in `H2O`, isn't `neuralnet` capable of deep learning?

Comment: broccoli - Do you have benchmarking results indicating that H2O's Deep Learning is slower than alternative CPU-based methods, for comparable amount of work (#epochs, #neurons, #hidden layers)?

Answer (score 1):

a simple search on google shows R package deepnet is doing DNN :

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deepnet/deepnet.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Now we have MXNet.
But if we jump a little bit(to python), there are several nice packages like Tensorflow,Keras,Mxnet,Caffe, etc.